# How to fix indexPath error in viewDIdLoad?

Tags: swift, sorting, struct, viewdidload, indexpath

I have problem with `indexPath.row`. Inside the `cellForRowAt` this lines work perfect:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MenuViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MenuViewCell

        let item = converters[indexPath.row]
        cell.ConverterName.text = item.converterName
        cell.converterImage.image = item.converterImg
```

But when i try to implement it inside viewdidload i've got an error: 
"Use of unresolved identifier 'indexPath'"

And code:

```
struct converter {
        let converterName: String
        let converterImg: UIImage
    }

var converters = [converter(converterName: "Converter of time", converterImg: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "time")),
                  converter(converterName: "Converter of pressure", converterImg: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "davlenie")),
                  converter(converterName: "Converter of speed", converterImg: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "skorost")),
                  converter(converterName: "Converter of distance", converterImg: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "dlinna"))]



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let item = converters[indexPath.row]
    let itemSort = item.converterName
    self.converters = itemSort.sorted { $0 < $1 }
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Comment: You will not get `indexPath.row` in `viewDidLoad` method. Why you need that in `viewDidLoad` method? what is your requirement?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni I making a multi language app so I want to sort cells in alphabetical order when ViewController is loaded

Comment: if you want to sort `Converters` based on name use in viewdidload `converters = converters.sorted(by: { (obj1, obj2) -> Bool in
            obj1.converterName > obj2.converterName
        })`

Comment: That works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad` is not passed an IndexPath parameter like `cellForRowAt` is.

IndexPath is used to identify either the current cell to be built or selected. You do not need it in viewDidLoad. You have 4 converters in the array and can select any you like whenever you need to just by using its index.